# Typescript infer keys of record in function

Tags: typescript

I would like to restrict the parameter that is passed when executing the next function, allowing only the keys of the object passed as a parameter in createTransitions. Of course it needs to be generic, as each transition will have different keys.

```
type Context = { [key: string]: any };

type Action<T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }> = (
  context: Context,
  next: (state?: keyof T) => void,
) => Promise<any> | any;

type Transitions<T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Action<T>;
};

export function createTransitions<T extends { [K in keyof T]: Action<T> }>(
  transitions: T,
): Transitions<T> {
  return transitions;
}

const transitions = createTransitions({
  trans1: (context) => {
    context.payload = context.request.json();
  },
  trans2: (context, next) => {
    if () {
      next("trans3"); // I want this to be valid
      return;
    }

    next("error"); // I want this to be valid
  },
  trans3: (context) => {
    next("any"); // I want this to be invalid
  },
  error: (context) => {
    //
  },
});
```

Full code: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/frosty-glade-jqkl68)

Comment: ① Please include any code necessary to understand the question here as plaintext, so that it's a [mre].  What is `Context` supposed to be? Can we just use `any`? Is there a reason you are calling `next("any")` when `next` isn't defined? ② Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NB1ADw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  Will you edit to fix your example code, or do you mind if I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that when the function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, a full object type whose keys you care about, the sort of self-referencing inference you need doesn't work... most likely because the compiler thinks that `T` depends on the type of `next` for each property, but `next`'s callback parameter depends [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) on `T`. The fact that it only needs to look at the *keys* of `T` isn't obvious to the compiler, so it fails to infer. There is an open issue for the general problem of trying to infer both generic type arguments and callback parameters contextually where there is an *apparent* but not *actual* circularity; see [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599). Until and unless something major changes there, we'll need to approach this in a different way.

It really seems like you don't care much about an object type, but instead just about its keys.  So let's make the function generic in `K`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys of your `T`.  That leads us to:

```
type Action<K extends PropertyKey> = (
    context: any,
    next: (state?: K) => void,
) => Promise<any> | any;

export function createTransitions<K extends PropertyKey>(
    transitions: Record<K, Action<K>>
) {
    return transitions;
}
```

This is essentially the same as yours, except that we are replacing `keyof T` with `K`.  And when we try it:

```
const transitions = createTransitions({
    trans1: (context) => {
        context.payload = context.request.json();
    },
    trans2: (context, next) => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            next("trans3"); // okay
            return;
        }

        next("error"); // okay
    },
    trans3: (context, next) => {
        next("any"); // error!
        //   ~~~~~
        // Argument of type '"any"' is not assignable to parameter of type
        // '"trans1" | "trans2" | "trans3" | "error" | undefined'.
    },
    error: (context) => {
        //
    },
});
```

it works. The compiler is happy to infer `K` from the keys of the input and then contextually type `next` from that. It sidesteps the circular inference problem because the compiler doesn't need to know the types of the properties of `transitions` in order to determine `K`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3&ssl=13&ssc=27&pln=12&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYB4DSUIA9gSoAmAzlAAoBOyklomEIAfFALxQAUAUFL1HGgL4AXFACGqEABoefVHmCiOJYGIIB+UZgCUbFgDdkiIjN2sWVZAFtEJCOgnMoAH3GSA3Fy54wyOlAAzAFdUBBRUfkoINQgAFUoJEkQkNBIsHHxCUgpqWnpGJm4+KGAE1CSU8tEAJQgBSiIsKVgwtCwmJi5dAG9ZXijgIMoI0sTk8JJPAF8vAXLgErKKibZI6IJ4scqSDl7i0fKARiU5oWAzFj3ivlOFADowMRAAG2QxIlXb-DuogEcgiAqO4AKxIaA42k8xSmMn2SwATCdBApmvJ8BcoFdrlBEAFOABZNQACx+EiI1ghUHQUAADHcAKw9PrYuQKDgAIgOJAAzOzIVAAPQCqDIADWT2ZLKgAyGqChLJmktZ+A5EEo1EofPcguFYol0NhfC53KRqDOqIUGKx1zRwA5ji1Opw6r8AEIlbwhXwAH6+30ep0wSgAcyCVkIC2QeNAkCgAHJ2Q64ziyKhkAsxCQksHUGIAEbPaDAZBQR4JcMESgi6PgCABr0JrmHdkuKCchEt1ztxK81vstUaztQEJECABRDyIhxu7MmHMgd+U1nK31gWzmRTSFAA)